# Windows Bootcamp stuck in infinite boot loop

Tags: bootcamp

I have a Mac Mini which I bought a few months ago onto which I installed Windows 10 Pro as a bootcamp partition. Everything was fine until the windows update assistant started to update it the other day. It now boots straight to the windows logo then flickers and says something like 'attempting to restore previous version of windows' for a split second and then says 'restoring previous version of windows' for another split second. Then it just loops constantly like this.

I have tried using the USB key I used to install it and going into the recovery options. It won't let me roll back the version and none of the recovery options work basically. It just reverts back to the above loop.

I have the partition backed up as an image so can restore but would prefer to avoid doing this and just fix it somehow.

It boots into the Mac OS absolutely fine. It's just the windows installation that is currently inaccessible.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks.

---

Thanks for the suggestions. I still can't get it fixed. Here is a screenshot of diskutil list. There is nothing to boot windows   Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: I do not have a good answer. Although, I would recommend turning off automatic updating so your Windows will not blowup unexpectedly in the future.

Comment: What if you boot into Safe Mode (hold the Shift key down while booting Windows. What happens then?

Comment: You mentioned you've added a screenshot, but that failed.

Comment: The screenshot should be there now.

Answer (score 1):

Had the exact same problem.

1. Created a Windows 10 bootable USB using the Media Creation Tool.
2. Once done, insert, switch the mini on, and when you hear the startup tone, immediately press and hold the alt key on your keyboard.
3. Select EFI Boot. At the prompt, choose No.
4. Select Language to install etc etc, then click Next.
5. Don't click Install Now. At the bottom left, select Repair Your Computer.
6. You might be asked to choose your keyboard layout. Choose UK or US, whichever is quicker.
7. Now select Use Another Operating System.

You should see several options, select one. If it doesn't work, repeat above steps, and try the next and then the next.

Should you eventually end up successfully booting into Windows, RUN > CMD. Type msconfig and hit enter. Find the problematic boot records and remove them. Be very careful not to remove the one that actually boots you in.

If you're successful, pause for a moment, and then take your time at thanking Microsoft for nothing.